# Is it possible to not target the banner in the body?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, coldfusion

I am having an issue.. I would for the banner to increase in size with the browser expands but not the content of the body. So I figured to not allow the body content to expand, I would do the following media query:

```
   @media (min-width:1281px){
    #homepage .carousel .carousel-caption { 
        left:auto;
        right:auto;
        max-width:1263px;
        margin-left:70px;
    }
    /*.footer-links{
        margin:auto;
        max-width:1263px;
    }
    .bodyPages{
        margin:auto !important;
        max-width:1263px !important;
    }
    #searchForm{
        margin:auto !important;
        max-width:1263px !important;
    }
    }*/
    /*.content-wrapper{
        margin:auto;
        max-width:1263px !important;
    }
    .carousel-wrapper{
        max-width:100%;
    }*/
    body{
        max-width:1263px !important;
        margin:auto;
    }
    :not(.carousel-inner img){

    }
    .carousel-inner img {
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfinclude template="inc/html_head.cfm" />
<body id="#$.getTopID()#" class="#$.createCSSHook($.content('menuTitle'))#" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".subnav" data-offset="50">
    <!--- <cfinclude template="inc/navbar.cfm" /> --->
    <!--- Navbar's display below is set to absolute position --->
    <cfinclude template="inc/navbar_ap.cfm" />
    <div id="resizable-section">
        <!---
            The Carousel/Slideshow
            Refer to the theme's contentRenderer.cfc for details on this method and its arguments/options
            NOTES: 
                * This theme is designed for Mura 6.1+
                * Only content items with an 'Associated Image' will be rendered
                * You can control the crop of the carousel image by using the custom defined 'carouselimage' image size // 'carouselimage'
        --->
        <!--- #$.dspCarouselByFeedName(
            feedName='Slideshow'
            , showCaption=true
            , cssID='myCarousel'
            , size='carouselimage'
            , interval=5000
            , autoStart=true
        )# --->
            #$.dspCarouselByFeedName(
            feedName='Slideshow'
            , showCaption=true
            , cssID='myCarousel'
            , size='custom'
            , interval=10000
            , autoStart=true
        )#
            <div class="container-fluid bodyPages">
                <div class="row">
                        <!-- expanded width of the following section. -->
                        <!--<section class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 content">-->
                        <section class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 content" id="home-content">
                        <!--- The content --->
                            #$.dspBody(
                                body=$.content('body')
                                , pageTitle=''
                                , crumbList=false
                                , showMetaImage=false
                            )#
                            <!--- Display Objects assigned to display region 2 (Main Content) --->
                            #$.dspObjects(2)#
                        </section>
                            <aside class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">-->
                            <!--- Display Objects assigned to display region 3 (Right Column) --->
                            <!--#$.dspObjects(3)#-->
                        <!--</aside>-->
                </div><!--- /.row --->
                <cfinclude template="inc/footer.cfm" />
            </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.resizable-text -->
<cfinclude template="inc/html_foot.cfm" />
```

Comment: I see you are using Mura. Couple of things from the code you posted. First, when you call the `dspCarouselByFeedName()` method with a size of custom `, size='custom'` I believe you need to specify the width and height as well. Otherwise use a predefined size from within Mura. Second, you are using Bootstraps `container-fluid` class. This is what causes your text content to "move" as the browser is resized. It is _fluid_ and utilizes all of the browser width. If you don't want that then just use the `container` class. I have read your question a couple of times and I'm still not sure what ...

Comment: you are after. Are you trying to resize the carousel image with the browser resize?  Or are you trying to resize the content text?  Can you please clarify in your question - [edit]

Comment: @Miguel-FThe content of the page, meaning the links, text, footer and so on stays in the middle without changing in size when the browser resizes. However, the carousel, I would like it to expand as the browser expands

Comment: So I thought it would be ideal to target the body for it will target all pages and subpages of the site. I am currently trying to use :not() css but it is not working as I hoped

Comment: No, you need to target the carousel itself because as you said you do not want to affect the other page content. Since Mura provides the carousel with an id as well as css classes your changes will be included on all pages that use a carousel (if you do it right). Assuming you are using the default Bootstrap that comes with Mura they are defining the homepage carousel here - https://github.com/blueriver/MuraCMS/blob/develop/default/includes/themes/MuraBootstrap3/css/theme/custom-theme.less#L209-L261  I think it will only stretch to your carousel image's size dimensions. What are the dimensions

Comment: It looks like the default theme is only letting those carousel images max at 1200px wide. See the class def here - https://github.com/blueriver/MuraCMS/blob/develop/default/includes/themes/MuraBootstrap3/css/theme/responsive/screen-sm.less#L14-L16  Have you made changes there to see how that affects your carousel?

Comment: @Miguel-F I feel I wasnt clear, let me explain myself. I do want to effect the other pages and subpages. So I thought it was ideal to call the body tag and center everything in the body which works great. I dont have to go to each template and manually do it. However, for the home page, it I would like the carousel to expand only. I was targeting the carousel but it still does not expand. As you can see in the css, I called it and nothing happen and yes on the bootstrap but I do have an override on the certian bootstrap css. I have targeted the image that are used for carousel but it effects

Comment: all images and I am still new to Coldfusion and Mura. I did not know about that file and I thank you. I have tried as you suggested to change the max-width to 100%. However, the body is constricting to 1281px which is the ideal size when the browser size is larger then 1281px. I thought by using :not(), call a specific class or id, wrap the carousel in a div, it would allow the image to increase in size but it doesn't

Comment: The body tag is the container for ALL of the content, so if you restrict it's size then you restrict the carousel image size as well. I think you would be better off using the `container` class instead of `container-fluid`. That will limit your content width and center it.  You don't have to make this change on all pages, just within the template(s).  Then I think the CSS changes will take affect on your carousel the way you are wanting.

Comment: I have tried changing it to container but it still restricts it to the size of the body width I suggested. Plus the other pages are using different columns based on the content on the page

Comment: So I felt it was best just to call the boy and center everything....

Comment: @Miguel-F I have tried that but it doesn't for the subpages, that is the problem I am having. if you had any other suggestion, I am willling to try them. Thaks

Comment: @Miguel-F Thank you for your help, I figured out another way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you're having is because you're setting a max width for the entire body, and your banner is within the body. This means that your banner will never be able to be larger than the 1263px max-width you specified.

Rather than change the size of the entire body you need to create a wrapper for your content. You also need to create a wrapper for your banner.

Here's some HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="banner">
    Banner Content goes here
</div>


<div class="content-wrapper">
    Page content goes here
</div>


</body>
```

and some CSS:

```
body {width:100%;}

.content-wrapper {
    max-width:1263px;
}

.banner-wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I have tried something like that but it doesnt work. The sections of the body start to move in different positions. The reason I targeted the body is because I would have to go to each page on the website and add the class or id to it. This way, it is clean and simple.

Comment: Well, the way that I have given you is the proper way to set up a website layout. It makes things easier to understand and to modify. However, put your HTML into your post so that it's easier for me to see what's actually going on.

Comment: it is in coldfusion. Still figuring out how it works. Will post it soon

Comment: I have posted it, not sure which container to call because I have tried most of them